# linux mdadm dm0 assembly error: md: cannot handle concurrent replacement and reshape. (machine reboot while reshaping)

Tags: linux, debian, linux-kernel, raid, software-raid

I have an issue with my linux raid setup and I hope somebody here could help me get my raid active again without data loss.

I have a debian 11 system with one raid array (**6x** 1TB hdd drives, raid level 5 ) that was active running untill today, when I **added two more** 1TB hdd drives and also changed the raid level to 6.

Note: For completition: My raid setup **month ago** was

```
mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 -c 256K --level=5 --raid-devices=6  /dev/sdd /dev/sdc /dev/sdb /dev/sda /dev/sdg /dev/sdf
mkfs.xfs -d su=254k,sw=6 -l version=2,su=256k -s size=4k /dev/md0
mdadm --detail --scan | tee -a /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf
update-initramfs -u
echo '/dev/md0 /mnt/data ext4 defaults,nofail,discard 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

**Today I did**:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdg /dev/sdh
sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --level=6
```

This started a growth process, I could observe with

```
watch -n 1 cat /proc/mdstat
```

and md0 was **still usable all the day**. Due to speedy file access reasons **I paused the grow and insertion process** today at about 50% by issuing

```
echo "frozen" > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action
```

After the file access was done, I restarted the process with

```
echo reshape > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action
```

but I saw in mdstat that reshape started form the scratch and not 50%. **After a five minutes I noticed, that /dev/dm0 mount was gone** and I rebooted the computer, to see if the kernel would reassemble dm0 correctly. Maybe the this was a problem, because the dm0 was still reshaping, I do not know..

(Note, for some reason the drive sdx letter orders changed after boot, but I did not change any devices)

After reboot dm0 was not reassembled and I couldn't reassemble it manually. When I try to assemble, there is always an Error

```
mdadm --assemble --run --force --update=resync /dev/md0 mdadm:
failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md0: Input/output error
```

Due to the interruption while growing I'm not sure now,

1. if my raid set actually a raid5 or raid6
2. if I have to attach the first 6 devices to raid or all 8
3. how to resolve the issue stated in all logs:

   mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdf /dev/sdi /dev/sdj /dev/sdg/dev/sdh
   mdadm --run --force /dev/md0

Results:

```
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 7 drives - need 8 to start (use --run to insist). 
mdadm: failed to start
    array /dev/md0: Input/output error
```

my dmesg log for this:

```
srv11:~# dmesg |tail
[ 3393.321837]  sdf:
[ 3415.020629] md/raid:md0: not clean -- starting background reconstruction
[ 3415.020771] md/raid:md0: device sdj operational as raid disk 4
[ 3415.020773] md/raid:md0: device sdi operational as raid disk 5
[ 3415.020774] md/raid:md0: device sdf operational as raid disk 0
[ 3415.020775] md/raid:md0: device sdc operational as raid disk 2
[ 3415.020776] md/raid:md0: device sdb operational as raid disk 1
[ 3415.023097] md: cannot handle concurrent replacement and reshape.
[ 3415.023551] md/raid:md0: failed to run raid set.
[ 3415.023553] md: pers->run() failed ...
```

I do not know how to deal with this error " md: cannot handle concurrent replacement and reshape." and could not find anything about in on the web.

I have seen that two drives (probably the new) have "Events : 0", while the other 6 all have "Events : 4700" in mdadm --examine.

Could anyone give me an **advice how to reactivate** this array **or atleast rescue my data** from it ?

I've tried to forcefully assemble it with no success, it seems that the raid is missing information on how many raid members there actually are and in what state.. First mdadm -D /dev/md0 showed only 6 members of the raid, then I added the other two one more time, now they are treated as spare.. yet, one seems to be ignored totally.

```
srv11:~# mdadm -v  --run --force  /dev/md0 
mdadm: failed to start array /dev/md0: Input/output error
srv11:~# mdadm -D /dev/md0 
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Mon Mar  6 18:17:30 2023
        Raid Level : raid6
     Used Dev Size : 976630272 (931.39 GiB 1000.07 GB)
      Raid Devices : 7
     Total Devices : 7
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Thu Apr 27 17:36:15 2023
             State : active, FAILED, Not Started 
    Active Devices : 5
   Working Devices : 7
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 2

            Layout : left-symmetric-6
        Chunk Size : 256K

Consistency Policy : unknown

        New Layout : left-symmetric

              Name : solidsrv11:0  (local to host solidsrv11)
              UUID : 1a87479e:7513dd65:37c61ca1:43184f65
            Events : 4700

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       -       0        0        0      removed
       -       0        0        1      removed
       -       0        0        2      removed
       -       0        0        3      removed
       -       0        0        4      removed
       -       0        0        5      removed
       -       0        0        6      removed

       -       8       32        2      sync   /dev/sdc
       -       8        0        -      spare   /dev/sda
       -       8      144        4      sync   /dev/sdj
       -       8       80        0      sync   /dev/sdf
       -       8       16        1      sync   /dev/sdb
       -       8      128        5      sync   /dev/sdi
       -       8       96        4      spare rebuilding   /dev/sdg
```

I can see in syslog that this error occured already at bootup while md assembly and I could not figure out how to get the array working again.. It seems that **the RaidDevice 3 is not found**..

Bootup syslog snip:

```
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel:  sde: sde1 sde2 sde3 sde4
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel:  sdj:
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel:  sdg: sdg1 sdg2 sdg3
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel:  sdc:
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel:  sda:
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel:  sdi:
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel:  sdh: sdh1 sdh2 sdh3
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel:  sdf:
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdj] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 0:0:1:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 0:0:2:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 2:0:0:0: [sde] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 5:0:0:0: [sdi] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 0:0:3:0: [sdf] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 4:0:0:0: [sdh] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: sd 1:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: raid6: sse2x4   gen() 12392 MB/s
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: raid6: sse2x4   xor()  7042 MB/s
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: raid6: sse2x2   gen() 11331 MB/s
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: raid6: sse2x2   xor()  7148 MB/s
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: raid6: sse2x1   gen() 10382 MB/s
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: raid6: sse2x1   xor()  6645 MB/s
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 gen() 12392 MB/s
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: raid6: .... xor() 7042 MB/s, rmw enabled
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx       
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: async_tx: api initialized (async)
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdf operational as raid disk 0
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdb operational as raid disk 1
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: md/raid:md0: device sda operational as raid disk 3
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdi operational as raid disk 5
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdc operational as raid disk 2
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: md/raid:md0: device sdj operational as raid disk 4
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: md: cannot handle concurrent replacement and reshape.
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: md/raid:md0: failed to run raid set.
Apr 27 17:37:05  kernel: md: pers->run() failed ...
```